# Is there a way to collect all Github action workflow results in one place?

Tags: github, github-actions, github-flavored-markdown

We have a Github organisation with several Repository's with multiple workflows in each.

We have made use of Status badges in the README but it would be nice to have a web page or something similar that can display the latest results of each workflow.

Are there any good guides or suggestions on best way to do this?

Thanks

Comment: the audit log of an organisation collects _some_ data -- you could look at that

Answer (score 3):

There isn't any webpage doing this for you (yet), but you could use the [Github API for actions](https://docs.github.com/en/rest/reference/actions) to get those informations, as there are interesting services available to get those datas:

- [List repository workflows](https://docs.github.com/en/rest/reference/actions#list-repository-workflows)
- [List workflow runs for a repository](https://docs.github.com/en/rest/reference/actions#list-workflow-runs-for-a-repository)
- [Get a workflow run](https://docs.github.com/en/rest/reference/actions#get-a-workflow-run)

After listing all the workflow repos and runs, you could get the status of the last runs and update them using a CRON JOB ou something similar.